# Como usar QVector<QVector <double> > como matriz?

Tags: array, c++, matriz, qt

Na `mainwindow.h` tenho:

```
private:
QVector<QVector<double> > numbers; //Variável que será minha matriz
public slot:
void realizar_calcs(QVector<QVector<double> > &numbers);
```

Na `mainwindow.cpp`

```
void MainWindow::realizar_calcs(QVector<QVector<double> > &numbers)
{
   int n1 = 10;
   numbers.resize(n1);
   for(int i = 0;i < n1;i++)
   {
      numbers[i].resize(n2);
   }
}
```

Minha dificuldade é na sua inicialização e na passagem para função!

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Um vetor não foi feito para se comportar como uma matriz. Claro que existem algumas soluções.

Achei uma [solução que parece se aproximar do que você deseja](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6333783/221800), veja se ajuda. Ela mostra como inicializar o vetor como se fosse uma matriz.

Existe uma [classe na Qt para isto](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qmatrix.html) mas ela foi considerada obsoleta e até onde eu sei nada foi criado para substituí-la. mas tem uma [classe mais moderna](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qmatrix4x4.html) na versão 4.6 em diante.

Outra opção óbvia é procurar uma classe que te atenda em outra biblioteca. Pode não ser tão simples integrar com a Qt.

Ainda existe a possibilidade de criar uma classe sua que funcione como matriz. Isto pode trazer algumas vantagens de integração com a Qt dependendo de como você faça.

Achei uma gambiarra [nessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12776872/221800):

```
int index(int x, int y) {
    return x + width * y;
}
```

Assim você simula uma matriz dentro do vetor:

```
QVector<...> vector(width * height);
vector[index(5, 3)] = ...;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Qt/Vector.cpp).

Comment: Pode até ajudar, mas para meu algoritmo ficaria muito confuso aplicar uma matriz dessa forma. Vi por aqui mesmo que fazendo dessa forma o QVector se aplica como matriz, minha dificuldade é na sua inicialização e como argumentos de entrada.

Comment: Cara sua gambiarra seria de bom tamanho se fossem estáticos, mas é utiliza aqui alocações. Mas mesmo assim muito obrigado

Comment: @carlosgoes2008 você viu a primeira solução? Ali faz a inicialização mais ou menos do jeito que você precisa (acho).